# How to show a small icon on right end of the tree node only on mouse over

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2, vue-component, element-ui

I'm trying to show an icon on treenode on mouseover of the same treenode.

```
Vue.component('tab', {

props:[],
data() {
    return{
        data: [{
          label: 'Level one 1',
          children: [{
            label: 'Level two 1-1'
          }]
        }, {
          label: 'Level one 2',
          children: [{
            label: 'Level two 2-1'
          }, {
            label: 'Level two 2-2'
          }]
        }, {
          label: 'Level one 3',
          children: [{
            label: 'Level two 3-1'
          }, {
            label: 'Level two 3-2'
          }]
        }],
    defaultProps: {
      children: 'children',
      label: 'label'
   }
 }
},  
methods: {
},
template: `<el-tree :data=data :props="defaultProps"></el-tree>`
})

var vm=new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

A small icon should be visible as marked in the below picture.
  [image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN5oM.png]

Here's the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/8hdm2ykb/

Comment: Looks like you're using a 3rd party library to display that tree, refer to their documentation for how to style it. If that's not possible you might be able to override a global style for the `tree-node-class:hover` in your app.

Comment: @TommyF: You are right with your advice, but I think it was not very helpful without an example

Answer (score 1):

Add following to your css

```
.el-tree-node__content:hover {
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/RZfgbVH.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 50px 100%;  
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8hdm2ykb/12/

replace background-image with the image you want to show and set background-size to your own requirement.